# URL redirect with Nested RewriteCond in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm migrating from an old url:

```
example.com/video?id=40
```

to a new one:

```
example.com/video/name-of-video
```

But them don't share any field, so i can't make a single rule for all and i have to write a rewritecond for every video i have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=3$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=5$
...
```

So i have more than 6000 rewritecond that slows the web.
What i want to achieve is to check if the url has the query string 'id=(.*)' and if has it, then check which id has to redirect to the correct video. So i want something like:

```
# IF
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$

# THEN
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=3$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/video/name-of-video? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=5$

# ELSE DO NOTHING
```

So on every load page, only checks one rewritecond instead of 6000, avoiding to slow down the web

Comment: With that many rules, it's going to be a little slower either way because .htaccess is read on every request. You should put this in your **Apache config** instead and once read into memory it's already there. Then turn off the use of .htaccess. Then it won't be slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep first rule as as **bail out rule**:

```
# IF
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=\d+$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This will not evaluate any rule below this if `?id=<number>` is not present in query string.